# AppVeyor: Upload to PyPI seems stuck

Tags: pypi, appveyor

When trying to upload my successfully built and tested python wheel to PyPI, the AppVeyor console log just displays `running upload` until I cancel the build.

This is the [appveyor.yml](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/appveyor.yml) I set up.

Any ideas on how I can find out what is going on?

Comment: Try looking via RDP (https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) - there might be a prompt asking for credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `twine` instead of `setup.py upload` using the previously generated wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while running Python builds on my Jenkins server. The build was just indefinitely waiting on "running upload". I found out that there was a prompt for a password by manually running the build in a console.

To avoid this, the documentation states that the `register` and `upload` commands both check for the existence of a `.pypirc` file in the HOME directory. See the [Package Index documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/packageindex.html#the-pypirc-file). By creating a file and adding the correct credentials within, the upload went through without the need to manually enter a password.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried to do: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/appveyor.yml   For some reason `twine` accepted the credentials in the `.pypirc`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The root-cause was (in my case) that I accidentally overwrite the `.pypirc` and the `twine` waits for username and password. (See [this diff](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/commit/dfa75f54520758f832ec269eb07ccb65b22911fb#diff-180360612c6b8c4ed830919bbb4dd459) for more details.)

[This github issue](https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/224) describes the same problem.

There will be a [new command line arg](https://github.com/pypa/twine/pull/489) `--non-interactive` for twine soon to help on this issue.